# Python 3 encoding/decoding problems between FreeBSD/Linux BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have an application which modifys the contents of an xml file (via beautiful soup), then writes it to disk. Easy enough, on my development machine (Linux), I have this working code:

First off, lets load the file into soup:

```python
# load document
document = open(contentxml, encoding="utf-8")
# load into soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(document, "lxml")
# do soupy stuff here
with open(document.name, "w") as f:
    # soup is the beautiful soup data
    f.write(soup.decode("utf-8"))
```

Now this works all fine and dandy, now when I run the exact same code on the FreeBSD production system, I get the error:

```python
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa3' in position 8253: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So in that case, I thought I would try encoding the file, and then write that to disk:

```python
with open(document.name, "w") as f:
    # soup is the beautiful soup data
    # srting the output as you cannot write bytes
    soup_enc = str(soup.encode('utf8'))
    f.write(soup_enc)
```

Now this works without error, but this writes incorrect xml to the output file, as it outputs to

```
b'<myxmlcontent>'
```

Which in turn makes the end file useless, what is the best way around this for a clean solution that will work on both platforms?

**Note:**

Some reading online suggests not to open the original document, with a specified encoding e.g. do:

```python
# load document
document = open(contentxml)
# load into soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(document, "lxml")
# do soupy stuff here
with open(document.name, "w") as f:
    # soup is the beautiful soup data
    f.write(str(soup))
```

This works fine on Linux, but on FreeBSD it throws an error when performing the initial open(..) of:

```python
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 7551: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to write directly to a binary file, I needed to open it with the correct method, then write the encoded byte string:

```py
with open(document.name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(soup.encode('utf8'))
```